# Sequelize model methods (findOne,findAll,create etc) not working but sequelize.query methods are working on SQL Server 2008 database

Tags: node.js, database, sql-server-2008, model, sequelize.js

I have done same sequelize methods with Postgres database all things are working fine.Whenever I make a connection to a SQL Server 2008 database and hit the model method, I got the error and I am really stuck .I have done lot of R&D and could not find any solutions.Please help.
here is the code: -

```
 const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
    process.env.DB_DATBASE,
    process.env.DB_USERNAME,
    process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    {
        host: process.env.DB_HOST,
        dialect: 'mssql',
        dialectOptions: {
            options: {
                encrypt: false,
                enableArithAbort: false,

            }
        },
    },);

try {
    sequelize
        .authenticate()
        .then(async () => {
            console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log('Unable to connect to the database:', `enter code here`err);
        });
} catch (err) {
    console.log('an error occured', err);
}
const highRiskModel = sequelize.define(
    'QuestionTypes',
    {
        QuestionTypeID: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        QuestionTypeName: Sequelize.STRING
        // ...modelCommonAttributes
    },
    {
        paranoid: false,
        timestamps: true,
        freezeTableName: true,
        schema: 'dba',
        // ...modelRenameDateAttributes

    },
);
```

highRiskModel.findAll().then((res)=>{
console.log(res

});

```
I got this error:
```

Executing(default ): SELECT[id], [QuestionTypeID][QuestionTypeName], [createdAt], [updatedAt] FROM[QuestionTypes] AS[QuestionTypes];

```
node: internal / process / promises: 279
```

triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
^

```
Error
    at Query.run(/var/www / html / project / db_migrate_conserve / node_modules / sequelize / lib / dialects / mssql / query.js: 107: 25)at /var/www/html / project / db_migrate_conserve / node_modules / sequelize / lib / sequelize.js: 315: 28 at processTicksAndRejections(node: internal / process / task_queues: 96: 5)at async MSSqlQueryInterface.select(/var/www / html / project / db_migrate_conserve / node_modules / sequelize / lib / dialects / abstract / query - interface.js: 407: 12)
    at async Function.findAll(/var/www / html / project / db_migrate_conserve / node_modules / sequelize / lib / model.js: 1140: 21) {
name: 'SequelizeDatabaseError',
    parent: AggregateError
```

at RequestTokenHandler.onErrorMessage(/var/www / html / project / db_mi`enter code here`grate_conserve / node_modules / tedious / lib / token / handler.js: 379: 30)
at Readable.< anonymous > (/var/www / html / project / db_migrate_conserve / node_modules / tedious / lib / token / token - stream - parser.js: 26: 33)
at Readable.emit(node: events: 526: 28)
at Readable.emit(node: domain: 475: 12)
at addChunk(node: internal / streams / readable: 315: 12)
at readableAddChunk(node: internal / streams / readable: 289: 9)
at Readable.push(node: internal / streams / readable: 228: 10)
at next(node: internal / streams / from: 98: 31)
at processTicksAndRejections(node: internal / process / task_queues: 96: 5) {
sql: 'SELECT [id], [QuestionTypeID], [QuestionTypeName], [createdAt], [updatedAt] FROM [QuestionTypes] AS [QuestionTypes];',
parameters: undefined
},
original: AggregateError
at RequestTokenHandler.onErrorMessage(/var/www / html / project / db_migrate_conserve / node_modules / tedious / lib / token / handler.js: 379: 30)
at Readable.< anonymous > (/var/www / html / project / db_migrate_conserve / node_modules / tedious / lib / token / token - stream - parser.js: 26: 33)
at Readable.emit(node: events: 526: 28)
at Readable.emit(node: domain: 475: 12)
at addChunk(node: internal / streams / readable: 315: 12)
at readableAddChunk(node: internal / streams / readable: 289: 9)
at Readable.push(node: internal / streams / readable: 228: 10)
at next(node: internal / streams / from: 98: 31)
at processTicksAndRejections(node: internal / process / task_queues: 96: 5) {
sql: 'SELECT [id], [QuestionTypeID], [QuestionTypeName], [createdAt], [updatedAt] FROM [QuestionTypes] AS [QuestionTypes];',
parameters: undefined
},
sql: 'SELECT [id], [QuestionTypeID], [QuestionTypeName], [createdAt], [updatedAt] FROM [QuestionTypes] AS [QuestionTypes];',
parameters: { }
}

Comment: If possible, can you share the code in question so we can better understand the issue?

Comment: code added done

Comment: =What is the exact error message from SQL Server? And what if you execute the generated SQL query directly? Is it correct?

Comment: SQL query with seqeuelize working fine for CRUD